# I created a off/on button, but first time you use it you need to click twice

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create this: When you click the button(some text), other text will appear. Then when you click it again it will disappear.
The problem with my current code is that the first time it runes you need to click it twiceto show the text.

```
document.getElementById('read').onclick = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('text01');
    if(element.style.display === 'none'){
        element.style.display = 'inherit';
    } else {
        element.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

<div id="read">Read more</div></p>
<p id="text01">Vestibulum tempus nulla accumsan aliquet lacinia. Curabitur scelerisque augue nec nunc fermentum, ac cursus est sollicitudin. Mauris gravida nisi dui, hendrerit volutpat nibh scelerisque aliquet. Nullam efficitur volutpat tellus.</p>
```

Comment: @kyll fix it, sorry x)

Comment: Is the initial state 'none' or something else?

Comment: You missed the "u" in the title, and now you have a typo at the end of your text =p

Comment: Seems to work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/c9fnj1yj/
Post your HTML

Comment: @Chrillewoodz it is none.

Comment: Its not taking two clicks in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/evkog7cc/1/

Comment: @MatthewRapati done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript can set CSS properties using `style`, but it cannot read them unless they were set previously using JavaScript.

To access properties defined within a stylesheet, use [**`getComputedStyle()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead:

```js
document.getElementById('read').onclick = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('text01');
    if(getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('display') === 'none'){
        element.style.display = 'inherit';
    } else {
        element.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
#text01 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="read">Read more</div></p>
<p id="text01">Vestibulum tempus nulla accumsan aliquet lacinia. Curabitur scelerisque augue nec nunc fermentum, ac cursus est sollicitudin. Mauris gravida nisi dui, hendrerit volutpat nibh scelerisque aliquet. Nullam efficitur volutpat tellus.</p>
```

Alternatively, you could simply switch your two conditions.  `element.style.display` will default to the null string the first time you run it, in which case it will start the toggle between `inherit` and `none`:

```js
document.getElementById('read').onclick = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('text01');
    if(element.style.display === 'inherit'){
        element.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        element.style.display = 'inherit';
    }
}
```

```css
#text01 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="read">Read more</div></p>
<p id="text01">Vestibulum tempus nulla accumsan aliquet lacinia. Curabitur scelerisque augue nec nunc fermentum, ac cursus est sollicitudin. Mauris gravida nisi dui, hendrerit volutpat nibh scelerisque aliquet. Nullam efficitur volutpat tellus.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your app is requiring you to press the button twice it is more than likely due to the initial value of "element.style.display" being something other than "none". I would use a small debug script to pull what the initial value of "element.style.display" is.

IF the value is not "none" your code will make it "none" after the first button press and then "inherit" on the second button press.